# camera captured image intent to other activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

Its very common question seen on StackOverflow and I have tried almost every solution on SO. I still get a `NullPointerExeption` in `onAtivityResult- data`.

I have tried:

- http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html
- [Capture Image from Camera and Display in Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991319/capture-image-from-camera-and-display-in-activity)
- [how to pass captured/gallery image to next activity in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22325721/how-to-pass-captured-gallery-image-to-next-activity-in-android)
- http://hmkcode.com/android-camera-taking-photos-camera/
- [onActivityResult returned from a camera, Intent null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14558240/onactivityresult-returned-from-a-camera-intent-null)
- [android camera: onActivityResult() intent is null if it had extras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12564112/android-camera-onactivityresult-intent-is-null-if-it-had-extras)

The last code which I have tried for fourth time is given below:

**On Button Click:**

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File file=getOutputMediaFile(1);
                picUri = Uri.fromFile(file); // create
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, picUri); // set the image file
                    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
```

**getOutputMediaFile()**

```
 private  File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyApplication");

        /**Create the storage directory if it does not exist*/
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                return null;
            }

        }
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == 1){
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                    "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".png");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }
```

**onActivityResult()**

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && intent != null){


            Uri selectedImage = intent.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            //file path of captured image
            imagepath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            //file path of captured image
            File f = new File(imagepath);
            String filename = f.getName();
            cursor.close();
            Bitmap imageData = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename);
//            Bitmap imageData = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

            Intent i = new Intent(this, EditImageActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("path", imageData );
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Please suggest something better which is not mentioned in above links which I already have referred because that didn't work for me.

I am using Android Atudio, with *api 10+*.

Crash log:

```
10-12 17:48:49.934 25060-25060/com.example.dell.drawdemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-12 17:48:49.934 25060-25060/com.example.dell.drawdemo E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.dell.drawdemo, PID: 25060
10-12 17:48:49.934 25060-25060/com.example.dell.drawdemo E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.dell.drawdemo/com.example.dell.drawdemo.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-12 17:48:49.934 25060-25060/com.example.dell.drawdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3593)
10-12 17:48:49.934 25060-25060/com.example.dell.drawdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3636)
10-12 17:48:49.934 25060-25060/com.example.dell.drawdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151)
10-12 17:48:49.934 25060-25060/com.example.dell.drawdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1390)
10-12 17:48:49.934 25060-25060/com.example.dell.drawdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
10-12 17:48:49.934 25060-25060/com.example.dell.drawdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
10-12 17:48:49.934 25060-25060/com.example.dell.drawdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5334)
10-12 17:48:49.934 25060-25060/com.example.dell.drawdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-12 17:48:49.934 25060-25060/com.example.dell.drawdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-12 17:48:49.934 25060-25060/com.example.dell.drawdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
10-12 17:48:49.934 25060-25060/com.example.dell.drawdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:676)
10-12 17:48:49.934 25060-25060/com.example.dell.drawdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-12 17:48:49.934 25060-25060/com.example.dell.drawdemo E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-12 17:48:49.934 25060-25060/com.example.dell.drawdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.dell.drawdemo.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:131)
10-12 17:48:49.934 25060-25060/com.example.dell.drawdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5546)
10-12 17:48:49.934 25060-25060/com.example.dell.drawdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3589)
10-12 17:48:49.934 25060-25060/com.example.dell.drawdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3636) 
10-12 17:48:49.934 25060-25060/com.example.dell.drawdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151) 
10-12 17:48:49.934 25060-25060/com.example.dell.drawdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1390) 
10-12 17:48:49.934 25060-25060/com.example.dell.drawdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
10-12 17:48:49.934 25060-25060/com.example.dell.drawdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
10-12 17:48:49.934 25060-25060/com.example.dell.drawdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5334) 
10-12 17:48:49.934 25060-25060/com.example.dell.drawdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
10-12 17:48:49.934 25060-25060/com.example.dell.drawdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
10-12 17:48:49.934 25060-25060/com.example.dell.drawdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860) 
10-12 17:48:49.934 25060-25060/com.example.dell.drawdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:676) 
10-12 17:48:49.934 25060-25060/com.example.dell.drawdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: 10-12 17:20:27.534 17724-17724/com.example.dell.drawdemo E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.dell.drawdemo/com.example.dell.drawdemo.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: 10-12 17:20:27.534 17724-17724/com.example.dell.drawdemo E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-12 17:20:27.534 17724-17724/com.example.dell.drawdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.dell.drawdemo.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:129)

Comment: hope this can help - @ Jas

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33078397/issue-in-capture-image-using-camera-in-lollipop/33078733#33078733

Comment: @DrashtiKapadia edit your question with logcat output , its confusing to read in comments

Comment: logcat edited @Karan Mer

Comment: Have already tried that... nullpointer showing. @Naveen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi please try below code hope it will help you,

```
private final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
private final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
```

intent code for capture image

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
m_fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, m_fileUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);


public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int p_type)
{
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(p_type));
}


private File getOutputMediaFile(int p_type)
{
    File m_mediaFile;
    if (p_type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE)
    {

            m_buffer = new StringBuffer();

            m_buffer.append(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + File.separator).append("Image");
            File m_imageStorageFile = new File(m_buffer.toString());

            // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
            if (!m_imageStorageFile.exists())
            {
                if (!m_imageStorageFile.mkdirs())
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            // Create a media file name
            String m_timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new java.util.Date());
            m_buffer = new StringBuffer();
            m_buffer.append(m_imageStorageFile.getPath()).append(File.separator).append("IMG_").append(m_timeStamp).append(".jpg");
            m_mediaFile = new File(m_buffer.toString());

    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }

    return m_mediaFile;
}
```

write below code in your onActivityResult

```
protected void onActivityResult(int p_requestCode, int p_resultCode, Intent p_data)
{
        super.onActivityResult(p_requestCode, p_resultCode, p_data);
        if (p_resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            switch (p_requestCode)
            {
                case CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE:
                    m_selectedPath = m_fileUri.getPath();
                break;

            }
        }
}
```

Constant.MEDIA_DIRECTORY_PATH contains your directory path 
example :- mnt/sdcard0/android/com.example

Comment: can u please explain what is Constant in code ? @Android WebLineindia

Comment: what should be its type ? its showing cannot resolve symbol Constant. @AndroidWeblineindia

Comment: dont use constant , i have updated my answer please check .

Comment: `String m_timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat(Constant.TIME_STAMP_FORMAT, Locale.getDefault()).format(new java.util.Date());`   its in your updated answer  - @AndroidWeblinindia

Comment: and what should write on other activity where the captured image has to display. @AndroidWeblinindia

Comment: thanks it worked.. i cant vote so i commented here... but tell me about that m_timeStamp i have commeted that line, what should i write on behalf of Constant at there.   @AndroidWeblinindia

Comment: Use "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss" instead of Constant.TIME_STAMP_FORMAT. Also if it worked fine for you pl accept and upvote the answer so that it can be helpful for others too.

Comment: showing cannot resolve  "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss" @AndroidWeblinindia

Comment: Pl explain properly all the require things you want , I have explained what you actually needed. Or pl share what actual errors you are getting.

Comment: you have mentioned that `Use "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss" instead of Constant.TIME_STAMP_FORMAT`   i have appied that and it shows error that `CAN NOT RESOLVE SYMBOL yyyyMMdd_HHmmss` @@AndroidWeblinindia

Comment: Pl share your code , I think you have implemented some thing wrong. And I have edited above answer so check once.

Comment: If it work fines for u pl accept and upvote the answer as it will be helpful for others.

Comment: i cannot vote , i have mentioned it before dont have 15 rep, its 14. :p

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `NullPointerException` because when user goes to camera intent and by the time he captures the image the activity on which camera intent was hosted gets destroyed or recreated when user comes back from the camera intent. Duw to which `picUri` (path of image created from camera intent) returns `null` as no such object is in memory right now.

Save path of image like this :

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if(mImageCaptureUri!=null)
        savedInstanceState.putString("camera_image", picUri.toString());

    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

And Retrieve image path from this :

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("camera_image")) {
            picUri = Uri.parse(savedInstanceState.getString("camera_image"));
        }
    }

    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Referenced from already answered [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32722402/android-camera-onactivityresult-resets-photo-path-to-null/32723550#32723550).

Comment: sorry m new in anddroid and i didnt use this two method can you please explain how to use and where to put this ? and if we use this then no need to use onActivityResult method? -@vipul_asri

Comment: No, these methods are an addition to `onActivityResult()` method. You have to put these methods in the Activity just like `onActivityResult()`